# Testing listeners in Laravel 5.1

Tags: unit-testing, laravel, laravel-5

Is there an standard way to unit test `Listeners` in **Laravel 5.1** (not mocking the `Event::fire()`) or do you just instantiate it, call `handle()` with mocked params and make assertions, the oldschool way?

I read [Events](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/events) and [Testing](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/testing) and it doesn't really says anything about unit testing listeners.

Comment: Yeah. Just instantiate it with mocked objects and call `handle`. It's a class like any other.

Comment: I had more than one listener on event, so I could not trigger the event to test only one listener. Thus I went old school too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK it's totally up to you and your preferences. You could do either of the two approaches mentioned, but I actually don't test them at all. Instead I try to have only a very basic code in the Listener, and move all the logic into separate services. IMHO that makes code easier to understand and cleaner to unit test without mocking the hell out of it.